# QGIS gives dll errors after installation

Tags: qgis, dll

I'm having issues installing QGIS 3.10. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, with the same errors as a result.

Below you can read the setup.log.

*"2019/11/05 16:17:48 Starting OSGeo4W install, version 2.579
2019/11/05 16:17:48 using locales .1252
2019/11/05 16:17:48 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2019/11/05 16:17:48 Current Directory: C:\Users\schelsma\AppData\Local\Temp
2019/11/05 16:17:48 Root Directory: C:\OSGeo4W64
2019/11/05 16:17:48 Could not open service McShield for query, start and stop. McAfee may not be installed, or we don't have access.
2019/11/05 16:17:55 source: network install
2019/11/05 16:17:56 root: C:\OSGeo4W64
2019/11/05 16:17:58 Selected local directory: C:\Users\schelsma\AppData\Local\Temp
2019/11/05 16:17:58 Menu name: OSGeo4W
2019/11/05 16:17:59 net: Direct
Cached mirror list unavailable
get_url_to_membuf http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/mirrors.lst
getUrlToStream http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/mirrors.lst
getUrlToStream failed!
get_url_to_membuf failed!
Defaulting to empty mirror list
2019/11/05 16:18:52 source: network install
2019/11/05 16:18:57 source: network install
2019/11/05 16:19:08 root: C:\OSGeo4W64
2019/11/05 16:19:15 Selected local directory: C:\Users\schelsma\AppData\Local\Temp
2019/11/05 16:19:15 Menu name: OSGeo4W
2019/11/05 16:19:16 net: Direct
2019/11/05 16:19:21 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2019/11/05 16:19:21 Ending OSGeo4W install"*

When starting up QGIS, a series of dll errors are shown. Ending in this last error.
[image]

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to install from another mirror?

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue earlier. I did a search for qgis on my hard drive and deleted all of the results. Then I installed again and it worked.